# Update a user field with a generated text

Tags: user-registration

I'm a newby to WordPress and PHP. I'm trying to update a field to put in a unique number in a customer record as soon as they sign up. I've written something which I think should work, but for the love of Jah it won't do anything. Help!!!

```
add_action ('user_register', 'mailboxNumberGenerator', 10, 1);

function mailboxNumberGenerator($current_user)
{    
    $initialMailboxNum = 100000;

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Customer' ) );
    $user_query2 = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Subscriber' ) );
    $currentMailboxNum = $initialMailboxNum 
    + $user_query->get_total() + $user_query2->get_total();

    $newMailboxNum = $currentMailboxNum + 1;

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    update_user_meta ($user_id, 'nickname', $newMailboxNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hook already gives you user id, you don't need to `$current_user`.

```
add_action ('user_register', 'mailboxNumberGenerator', 10, 1);

function mailboxNumberGenerator($user_id)
{    
    $initialMailboxNum = 100000;

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Customer' ) );
    $user_query2 = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'Subscriber' ) );
    $currentMailboxNum = $initialMailboxNum 
    + $user_query->get_total() + $user_query2->get_total();

    $newMailboxNum = $currentMailboxNum + 1;

    update_user_meta ($user_id, 'nickname', $newMailboxNum);
}
```

Comment: The issue was resolved. There was really no issue with the code it appears. I was using a WooCommerce signup form which wasn't allowing me to write data to it after the fact. Using the WordPress builtin login form however didn't have this issue, hence the code did what it was expected to do. Thanks for your response though.